# Mage registry key "_singleton/weee/observer" already exists

Tags: magento-1.7, registry, singleton, key, ce-1.7.0.0

When I try to add or edit a product I receive the following error:

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/weee/observer" already exists
Trace:
#0 app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 app/Mage.php(476): Mage::register('_singleton/weee...', false)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('weee/observer')
#3 app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('adminhtml_catal...', Array)
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(143): Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_catal...', Array)
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(207): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->newAction()
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 index.php(124): Mage::run('catalog', 'website')
#24 {main}
```

Magento ver. 1.7.0.0
Compiler turned off
cleared cache
rebuilt index
no updates or new extensions have been installed it just quit working

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From my understanding this is caused by cache, are you sure it's cleared? How did you clear it?

Comment: I used Cache Management under System - Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage.  Is there a way to check if the cache has been flushed?

Comment: Assuming your using file based cache, check there is something inside the `var/cache` directory, if there is, delete everything in the folder.

Comment: Tried that, still getting errors.  At the very top of the screen there is also a reference to Linux sitename 3.8.0-41-generic #60~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 16 00:18:00 UTC 2014 x86_64
Thank you for your quick answers and your help!

Answer (score 18):

This error arriving due to empty values in registry.

to prevent it, you need to disable 'compilation' mode, and if you want to use it, re run it.

```
php -f shell/compiler.php disable
php -f shell/compiler.php clear
php -f shell/compiler.php compile
```

Comment: Tried clearing and disabling compiler and still getting the error.  Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Run Compilation works!!!

Comment: Abhishek you are my hero! This post fixed a problem I've spent hours at with similar error to above post. Compiling from admin panel causing error. But running from command line worked fine :)

Answer (score 5):

Check if your event observer xml code in your module's `config.xml` is all correct.

It should be something like this:

```
<events>
    <event_name_that_you_are_working_on>
        <observers>
            <some_unique_identifier>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>functionNameInYourObserver</method>
            </some_unique_identifier>
        </observers>
    </event_name_that_you_are_working_on>
</events>
```

I once got this kind of error because I was using `modulename/observer` inside class node. Using full class name (`YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer`) solved the error for me.

In your module's event-observer xml code, you might be using `class` like below:

```
<class>yourmodule/observer</class>
```

Try using this instead (as done in above event-observer xml code):

```
<class>YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the extension from `app\etc\moduels` directory.
2. Clear cache and
3. Run Compilation.

Now, it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First Disable Compilation and cache.

And Clear all cache forcefully.

Then install Extension.

After that Run Compilation process.

Above process worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To disable compilation in Magento, edit includes/config.php. At around line 28, uncomment the first line and comment out the second:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```