# Magento update order product on observer

Tags: magento-1.7, product, orders, event-observer

I'm trying to update **additional_data** field on **sales_flat_order_item** table in Magento.

For this I create a custom module

This is my Observer.php under app/code/local/Distelsa/Wedding/Models :

```
class Distelsa_Wedding_Model_Observer{

    public function AddWeddingIdToProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        $item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $item->getQuote();
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $controllerAction = $event->getControllerAction();
        $params = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams();
        $boda = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('boda');

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET additional_data = '".$params['boda']."' where item_id = ".$item->getId();
        $write->query($query);

    }
}
```

[Edited] This is my entire config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config>
<modules>
    <Distelsa_Wedding>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Distelsa_Wedding>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <wedding>
            <class>Distelsa_Wedding_Model</class>
        </wedding>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_before>
            <observers>
                <update_wedding_order>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>wedding/observer</class>
                    <method>AddWeddingIdToProduct</method>
                </update_wedding_order>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <wedding>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Distelsa_Wedding</module>
                <frontName>wedding</frontName>
            </args>
        </wedding>
    </routers>
</frontend></config>
```

Any clue on how can I make this works?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the observer to before save.

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_before>
            <observers>
                <sales_order_save_after_wedding>
                    <class>wedding/observer</class>
                    <method>AddWeddingIdToProduct</method>
                </sales_order_save_after_wedding>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

Since you are using `sales_order_save_after` you have to edit the order object and not quote.

```
public function dandanaka($observer){
    $controllerAction = $event->getControllerAction();
    $params = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams();
    $boda = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('boda');

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
         //todo: preserve any data that have be added by other module
         $item->setAdditionalData($boda);
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks R.S., I made the changes you tell me, and now I'm getting this alert/error: "Mage registry key "_singleton/distelsa_wedding/observer" already exists". I google it and I already disable and clear cache, also compiler it's disabled.

Comment: I forgot to metion you @R.S ↑↑

Comment: Please add you entire config.xml. Do you have any other module that uses `<sales_order_save_after_wedding>`?

Comment: Change  `<class>distelsa_wedding/observer</class>` to  `<class>wedding/observer</class>` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422867/magento-creating-an-event-to-extend-customer-creation-in-magento

Comment: No @R.S that didn't work, I still get the message: "Mage registry key "_singleton/wedding/observer" already exists". I update my orginal question with all the config.xml

Comment: Add `<models>...</models>` tag as per the previous link. Then do a search `sales_order_save_after_wedding` then clear cache

Comment: Still no luck @R.S It is possible that I need to make some changes on database?

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51598/mage-registry-key-singleton-weee-observer-already-exists

Comment: This is the point when I start to cry a lot. I already run compiler and clear cache, and still nothing. I even try to rename all my custom module and didn't work. @R.S