# Mage registry key "_singleton/belvgall/observer" already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, register, singleton

Mage registry key "_singleton/belvgall/observer" already exists

Trace:

```
#0 app\Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 app\Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/belv...', false)
#2 includes\src\__default.php(22026):Mage::getSingleton('belvgall/observ...')
#3 app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 includes\src\__default.php(14361): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 includes\src\Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 includes\src\__default.php(14241): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 includes\src\__default.php(18698): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 includes\src\__default.php(18228): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 includes\src\__default.php(21056): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

after i installed a extension then i got these error on magento 1.9.1

Comment: try to disable compilation and check again.

Comment: maybe helpful http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51598/mage-registry-key-singleton-weee-observer-already-exists

Comment: I disabled the compilation that's work for me...thanks

Comment: should i enable it back?

Comment: Yes it is enable back but after clear magento all cash