# SUPEE-1533, SUPEE-5344 Possible Problems?

Tags: magento-1.8, security, patches, supee-5344

I tried to install patches Magento SUPEE-1533, SUPEE-5344 CE 1.8.1 without ssh access direct file upload  but after install there's error both backend and website became unaccesable  so i replaced all files with old one

**SUPEE-1533**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
```

**SUPEE-5344**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

but there's error now when try to access backend . frontend is fine.

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/catalogsearch2/feed" already exists
```

[image]

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: @fschmengler  yes after install I clear and after replace files also

Comment: Given that the question was posted quite some time ago i think you might have fixed it inbetween. Here's a good explanatin: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/51628/231 Would be great if you could answer your own question how you solved it.