# Mage registry key already exists Error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, registry, key

I keep getting an error stating
" There has been an error processing your request
Mage registry key "em_current_theme" already exists

Then a bunch of Trace: numbers"

It happens on the mobile version of my site and i'm wondering if there is a quick fix to resolve this issue once and for all.

[image]

Comment: ran into this issue today. found this and it worked for me, take a look and see if this helps: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51598/mage-registry-key-singleton-weee-observer-already-exists

Comment: Have you installed some new extension, are added some data in registry ?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely caoused by some extension you have installed.

Try to disable the new extension you installed and disable the compiler. Then re-compile again.

You can do this from the admin panel or if it's not accessible try those commands:

```
php -f shell/compiler.php disable
php -f shell/compiler.php clear
php -f shell/compiler.php compile
```

You can also diable the module in `app\etc\modules` directory.