# when i open my website showing this error .Mage registry key "_singleton/log/visitor" already exists

Tags: singleton

[image]

I am a beginner in magento development . please help me

Comment: Check if Magento cache is cleared, for example by emptying the `var/cache/` directory.

Comment: Yes i have tried it but still same error

Comment: Try disable `compilation` mode Check here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/51628

Comment: I have tried that also. At first the error was "Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'processor.php' (include_path='/home/apd16/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/apd16/public_html/errors/report.php on line 28 " , then i have uploaded processor.php in errors folder after that the error changed to this registry key already exist

Comment: Try to install the fresh Magento on server and check if you still face such an issue.

Comment: what about session folder in var

Comment: session folder also cleared but same issue.

Comment: @BhaumikUpadhyay did you mean redesign?

Comment: @Aleena I meant to install Magento's new setup on your local.

Comment: ok i will try doing that. thank you